# How can I call a .js file in onclick event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I did like:

```
onclick="document.write('document.write(-------)');"
```

Comment: do you want to call a js function from a js file or include that js file in your page dynamically?

Comment: So you want to load an external JavaScript file on button/link click?

Comment: user709305 why do you want to do so? you could have just included the js file and used the functions in that js file. was doing that a harm?

Comment: I found the way...<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="var fileref=document.createElement('script');fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');  fileref.setAttribute('src', 'generate.js');document.body.appendChild(fileref);">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function importJavascript(src) {
    var tag = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    tag.src = src;
    document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(tag);
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onClick="theFunction();">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: No.I want to call the js file without using function.

Comment: @user You'll find it tough to include a JavaScript file without using any functions :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>function getJs(src, callback) {
    if (src && typeof src === "string") {
        var el = document.createElement("script");
        el.type = "text/javascript";
        el.src = src;
        document.head.appendChild(el);
        el.onload = function(e) {
            (callback && callback instanceof Function) ? callback(e) : void(0);
        }
    }
}
<script>

<div onclick='getJs("location_to_the_js_file.js")'></div>
```

Comment: Just a note, `typeof /regex/` is a `Function` in WebKit. I've always used `callback instanceof Function`.

Comment: but why would someone want to load a js file on click of something? is that a good practice or loading all the js files at the beginning a good one?

Comment: @Anji: Beats me. Not a good practice. But depending on the use it could crucial. Without any additional info, I can only answer the question as-is. :)

Comment: I found the way...<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="var fileref=document.createElement('script');fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javas­cript'); fileref.setAttribute('src', 'generate.js');document.body.appendChild(fileref);">

Answer (score 0):

what about using jQuery.getScript(), if you are using jQuery in your application already